# Javafx swipe event and tap on displayShelf component?

Tags: mobile, javafx, javafx-8, gesture, multi-touch

For mobile application i'm using displayShelf component, here is the download link for Ensemble:

download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/Ensemble.jnlp

When i add swipe left or swipe right events on displayShelf it works fine, but when i add touchpressed events on PerspectiveImage (see the code from the example) it conflicts with swipe event. In particular, perspective image catch focus and swipe event works just on the bottom of the displayShelf itself. I'd like to make an element slider that works with swipe, with the possibility to tap on the single element of the slider.

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer to my own question. Those are two ways i tried to solve it (i don't know how much elegant they are but is quite acceptable for me):

1) At the start of each swipe event, you can set null to setOnTouchPressed of each element (perspective Image), and, at the end of it, you can set the callback to execute on tap just of the center element. To do so, you can use timeline.setOnFinished().

2) You can modify PerspectiveImage class to make it accept nodes as argument of the constructor instead of Image. In this way you can pass a stackpane with a label on it (even without text) and, on the label, we have the callback for the tap we need already setted on it. In this way, you just need to disable all nodes except the one on the center each time we swipe. So you can """mix"""" this answer to the first solution.

Hope it can help someone